# Rspec: Avoiding out of sync issues with message expectations

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

Message expectations allow you to check if the object under test is sending the right message, but not that the target object can actually respond to this call. On the other end of the spectrum, integration testing checks that everything actually work, that is, that the calls are made, understood and executed properly.

Is there a middle ground, like checking that the object under test sends the right messages **and** that the receiving object can respond to these message ? This would ensure that the test break when the receiving object changes, without running a full integration test. In essence:

```
target.should_receive(:my_method) && target.should respond_to(:my_method)
```

using a custom matcher like

```
target.should_get_message(:my_method)
```

this could be useful for glue classes that just coordinate different actions I think.

What are your opinions on that ? Is it a viable approach ?

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [rspec-fire](https://github.com/xaviershay/rspec-fire) it solves this exact problem.  I've been using it in lots of projects.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very promising !